# Check table for similar text records and remove duplicate records (SQL Oracle database. )

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicates

I need to check an oracle database table for similar records and get the number of characters that differ. For this I use this query:

```
CREATE TABLE match_tab (
  id   NUMBER,
  col1 VARCHAR2(15),
  CONSTRAINT match_tab_pk PRIMARY  KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO match_tab VALUES (1, 'Peter Parker');
INSERT INTO match_tab VALUES (2, 'peter parker');
INSERT INTO match_tab VALUES (3, 'Clark Kent' );
INSERT INTO match_tab VALUES (4, 'Wonder Woman');
INSERT INTO match_tab VALUES (5, 'Superman');
INSERT INTO match_tab VALUES (6, 'The Hulk');
INSERT INTO match_tab VALUES (7, 'Ponder Woman');
INSERT INTO match_tab VALUES (8, 'Claire Kent' );
INSERT INTO match_tab VALUES (9, 'Superman');
INSERT INTO match_tab VALUES (10, 'Iron Man');
COMMIT;

select  m1.col1 as mc1, 
        m2.col1 as mc2,
        UTL_MATCH.edit_distance(m1.col1, m2.col1) as match
from match_tab m1
join match_tab m2 on (1 = 1)
where UTL_MATCH.edit_distance(m1.col1, m2.col1) = 2 and m1.id != m2.id;
```

which gives the result:

```
   MC1             MC2                  MATCH
--------------- --------------- ----------
Peter Parker    peter parker             2
peter parker    Peter Parker             2
Clark Kent      Claire Kent              2
Claire Kent     Clark Kent               2
```

1. How can I remove duplicate records and get result like this:

   ```
   MC1             MC2                  MATCH
   --------------- --------------- ----------
   Peter Parker    peter parker             2
   Clark Kent      Claire Kent              2
   ```
2. Is it possible to optimize this query? For a large amount of data,
   it takes a long time.

I would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can:

- use a hierarchical query so that you do not need to read the table twice and do not need to self-join;
- add filters to check that the length of the columns is similar (which may be a simpler comparison than using `UTL_MATCH` and the optimiser may be able to exclude a lot of comparisons if it uses this filter first); and
- filter on the `PRIOR id < id` rather than using `!=` to compare the `id`s and eliminate the duplicates:

```sql
SELECT PRIOR col1 as mc1, 
       col1 as mc2,
       UTL_MATCH.edit_distance(PRIOR col1, col1) as match
FROM   match_tab
WHERE  LEVEL = 2
CONNECT BY
       LENGTH(PRIOR col1) - LENGTH(col1) BETWEEN -1 AND +1
AND    PRIOR id < id
AND    UTL_MATCH.edit_distance(PRIOR col1, col1) BETWEEN 1 AND 2;
```

Which, for your sample data, outputs:

> | MC1 | MC2 | MATCH |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Peter Parker | peter parker | 2 |
> | Clark Kent | Claire Kent | 2 |
> | Wonder Woman | Ponder Woman | 1 |

*Note: if you only want matches where the edit-distance is `2` then change the last line to `AND UTL_MATCH.edit_distance(PRIOR col1, col1) = 2;`*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=52e82aa0da5e1133aca59f02f2f4f010)*

Answer (score 0):

Removing "duplicates" is simple (use e.g. `<` instead of `!=`):

```
SQL> SELECT m1.col1 AS mc1,
  2         m2.col1 AS mc2,
  3         UTL_MATCH.edit_distance (m1.col1, m2.col1) AS match
  4    FROM match_tab m1
  5         JOIN match_tab m2
  6            ON     UTL_MATCH.edit_distance (m1.col1, m2.col1) = 2
  7               AND m1.id < m2.id;

MC1             MC2                  MATCH
--------------- --------------- ----------
Peter Parker    peter parker             2
Clark Kent      Claire Kent              2

SQL>
```

---

How to make it faster? I don't know if you *can* make it any faster; you're comparing all rows, and - for large tables - it takes time.

I removed your cross-join (with `on 1 = 1`) as you actually can join `m1` and `m2` on `utl_match.edit_distance`, but I don't expect it to be a significant improvement to your code.